# I have to transit from T2 to T1 of Delhi airport in a same PNR ticket, will my luggage automatically be transferred from T2 to T1?

Tags: transit, airlines, new-delhi, indigo

I have to transit from T2 to T1 of Delhi airport.
Booked through Indigo under same PNR ticket.

Will my luggage automatically be transferred from T2 to T1 ?
Or should I wait for luggage and manually transfer luggage to t1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will my luggage automatically be transferred from T2 to T1 ?

Yes. Unless you have some unusual circumstances, your luggage will be transferred. If there is any doubt, just check directly with the airline.

See https://www.newdelhiairport.in/passenger-guide/transit-passengers